# Looping over a MST implementation using a PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am looping over a MST implementation using a PL/pgSQL function. Here is the function I am using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_pma_ranked() 
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    r RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT areaid, max_uuid FROM pma_ranked LOOP
        EXECUTE 
        '
        with RECURSIVE
        tree AS (
        SELECT
        g."centerPoint"::GEOMETRY AS vtcs,
        NULL::GEOMETRY AS segment,
        ARRAY[g.uuid] AS uuids
        FROM
        potential_missed_areas AS g
        WHERE
        g."areaID" = ''' || r.areaid || '''
        and g.uuid = ''' || r.max_uuid || '''
        and g.status = ''approved''
        UNION ALL   
        SELECT
        ST_Union(t.vtcs, v."centerPoint"),
        ST_ShortestLine(t.vtcs, v."centerPoint"),
        t.uuids || v. uuid
        FROM
        tree AS t
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT
        g.uuid,
        g."centerPoint"
        FROM
        potential_missed_areas AS g
        WHERE
        g."areaID" = ''' || r.areaid || '''
        AND g.status = ''approved''
        and
        NOT g.uuid = ANY(t.uuids)
        ORDER BY
        t.vtcs <-> g."centerPoint"
        LIMIT
        1
        ) AS v
        ),
        NumberedRows AS (
        SELECT
        uuids,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RowNum
        FROM tree
        WHERE segment IS NOT NULL
        )
        SELECT
        uuids
        FROM NumberedRows
        WHERE RowNum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM NumberedRows);
        ';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am then calling it as such:

```
select * from process_pma_ranked()
```

This results in an empty result set.

Please note, when I remove the loop, and run the MST code using hardcoded values as such:

```
with RECURSIVE
  tree AS (
    SELECT
      g."centerPoint"::GEOMETRY AS vtcs,
      NULL::GEOMETRY AS segment,
      ARRAY[g.uuid] AS uuids
    FROM
      potential_missed_areas AS g
    WHERE
      g."areaID"  =  '47ab0d86-4061-42f3-9cb5-078189fed9b8'
      and g.uuid = 'MA30356'
      and g.status = 'approved'
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT
      ST_Union(t.vtcs, v."centerPoint"),
      ST_ShortestLine(t.vtcs, v."centerPoint"),
      t.uuids || v. uuid  
    FROM
      tree AS t
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT
    g.uuid,
    g."centerPoint"
  FROM
    potential_missed_areas AS g
  WHERE
    g."areaID" = '47ab0d86-4061-42f3-9cb5-078189fed9b8'
    
    AND g.status = 'approved'
    and 
    NOT g.uuid = ANY(t.uuids)
  ORDER BY
    t.vtcs <-> g."centerPoint"
  LIMIT
    1
) AS v
  )       

 
  ,
  NumberedRows AS (
  SELECT 
    uuids,
    
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RowNum
  FROM tree
  WHERE segment IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
  uuids  
FROM NumberedRows
WHERE RowNum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM NumberedRows);
```

Then I get the correct results.

Is there something wrong in how the loop is being executed perhaps?